# how to create stored procedure in mysql with insert into select table statement

Tags: mysql

> how to create a stored procedure in MySQL with "insert into select
> table statement"
>
> sample sql query
>
> insert into table2 select * from table 1;
>
> table 1 and table 2 having same structure.

Comment: MYSQL stored procedures are very straightforward https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html. Did you try anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following SQL statement creates a stored procedure named **"CopyTable1"** that selects all records from the **"table1"** and copy into **"table2"**:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CopyTable1
AS
Insert into table2 select * from table1
GO;
```

Execute the stored procedure above as follows:

```
EXEC CopyTable1;
```

Comment: Mysql does not have go or exec. Mysql procedures require () in the create even if there no parameters , there is no AS and are CALLed not EXEXed..

Comment: But how to avoid to read the entire table (table1) on each execution?